# Substring in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a text that I call from database.

Here is my controller:

```
 .controller('selengkapCtrl',function($scope,$ionicHistory,$http,$stateParams){

    $scope.goBack = function(){
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    }

    // deklarasi variable
    var id_lapangan = $stateParams.id_lapangan;
    $scope.selengkap = [];
    $http.get("http://localhost/TA2/admin/app/getUserId.php?id_lapangan="+id_lapangan).success(function(data){   
        $scope.selengkap = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

and here is my template:

```
<ion-view ng-controllers="selengkapCtrl">
  <ion-content>
     <div class="row" ng-repeat="selengkap in selengkap">
        <p>{{selengkap.deskripsi}}</p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

for now. the result is like this.
[image: myView]
What I want is that the sentence cut and the result of the text is like this:
`"This Word is very long. How to"`

So, if I want to read the full description, I have to click that hyperlink text.
How to fix this problem?
any help would be glad to see it!
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get substring in ionic using ***[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)***

```
<p>{{(selengkap.sortdeskripsi.length > 30) ? (selengkap.sortdeskripsi | limitTo:30) : selengkap.sortdeskripsi}}</p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't <p>{{ selengkap.sortdeskripsi | limitTo:30 }}</p> be enough?

Comment: thanks man! it's working! but i want to ask, what the function of "?" in the middle of the code?

Comment: it is Conditional (Ternary) Operator (?:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $http.get("http://localhost/TA2/admin/app/getUserId.php?id_lapangan="+id_lapangan).success(function(data){   
            $scope.selengkap = data;

            if ($scope.selengkap.deskripsi.length > 30) {
                                $scope.selengkap.deskripsi = $scope.selengkap.deskripsi.substr(0, 30) + ' ...';
                            }

            console.log(data);
        })

    <ion-view ng-controllers="selengkapCtrl">
      <ion-content>
         <div class="row" ng-repeat="selengkap in selengkap">
            <p>{{selengkap.deskripsi}}</p>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>

        $http.get("http://localhost/TA2/admin/app/getUserId.php?id_lapangan="+id_lapangan).success(function(data){   
            $scope.selengkap = data;

            if ($scope.selengkap.deskripsi.length > 30) {
                                $scope.selengkap.sortdeskripsi = $scope.selengkap.deskripsi.substr(0, 30) + ' ...';
                            }

            console.log(data);
        })

  <ion-view ng-controllers="selengkapCtrl">
      <ion-content>
         <div class="row" ng-repeat="selengkap in selengkap">
            <p>{{selengkap.sortdeskripsi}}</p>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but this is not working. i'm using limitTo as Ved said. But i wonder how this is working too.